# Install some recommended packages

Tags: apt, kde, plasma

Is it possible in apt/apt-get to install a package and only some of its recommendations?

For example: I want to install `kde-plasma-desktop` which recommends `sddm`, but I don't want to install sddm. What I do want is to install the rest of the recommended packages.

Is there any way of doing this with apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try appending a dash to the end of the package you don't want installed, as in `apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop sddm-`. From `man apt-get`:

> If a hyphen is appended to the package name (with no intervening space), the identified package will be removed if it is installed. Similarly a plus sign can be used to designate a package to install. These latter features may be used to override decisions made by apt-get's conflict resolution system.

Comment: Well that works. I guess I missed that part of the man page while I was reading it. Thanks!